# Virtual box localhost access

Tags: networking, virtualhost, virtual-machines, virtualbox

Question on Virtual Box 4.1.8
So, i have Ubuntu 10.10 as host machine and Windows Xp as guest machine.
On host machine there is tomcat with web app running on port 8888.
When i am in guest machine i type in browser:
 
http://10.0.2.2:8888/Something.html and it works.
 But my Something.html has links to javascript like src="http://localhost:8888/webApp/someScript.js and they obviously aren't working(because of "localhost" part). 
The other problem is that i don't want to use relative path now, only absolute. Also i don't want to change localhost to Host Ip in my links
Maybe there is some solution, like port forwarding or network config of Virtual box, that i can type in my guest browser
http://localhost:8888/Something.html

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: I have no idea if Windows uses 'localhost' for anything internally (I don't think it does - but could be wrong). If it doesn't what you can do is to map 'localhost' to 10.0.2.2 (instead of the typical 127.0.0.1) on your Windows guest. Edit `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add/modify `10.0.2.2       localhost`. (On Linux this would definitely be a bad idea, but you might get away with it on Windows).

Comment: Already tried. It doesn't work. Windows Xp always maps localhost to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your real problem is that you want to do things that doesn't make sense for any kind of web app that should serve anything outside it's machine: You need links that work without tricks on the client machine, either with relative paths where applicable or non-local hostnames.

Of course there is a workaround:

Simply install Putty on Windows and use it to create a port forwarding from port 8888 on your machine to port 8888 on 10.0.2.2. You will find lots of links with Google that explains how this is done in Putty.

Afterwards, you can simply connect to `localhost:8888` and stuff *should* work.

Comment: this is awesome. once the ssh connection is established, the tunnel just works in the browser. for my setup, i forwarded 8080 to localhost:8080, since I wanted the localhost on the guest machine to hit the localhost of the host machine. here's a good ref for putty tunneling - http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/

Answer (score 2):

If you manually add a hostname for the host in `/etc/hosts` (on the host) and in `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` (on the guest), you can use that name in your code. And since both machine can resolve it it should work. As SvenW mentioned that's not the way one is supposed to solve it but should be fine for testing purposes.

Example of the `hosts` entry:

```
10.0.2.2 webapphoster
```

...and then you can call the js:

```
src="http://webapphoster:8888/webApp/someScript.js"
```